# What's the right domain name for this site?

Tags: discussion, site-name

The domain name for this site is `languagedesign.stackexchange.com`. I've been a programmer for more than two decades, but when I read it I still fail to comprehend it's about *programming* languages, unlike e.g. [our sister site about Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/). Also, the title says implementation questions are also in scope and encouraged. Isn't there a better third level domain than `languagedesign`?

Comment: Featuring this for visibility. We didn't love language design either, so happy to take suggestions.

Comment: Made the request to have the URL changed to langdev since its the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Can a mod mark this as status-completed

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about `langdev`? Short and memorable.

Comment: This was the one we informally agreed on in chat during definition

Comment: This has the same problem that Glorfindel mentioned in the question's body.

Comment: Sounds plusgood

Comment: `pl-dev` might be better? Does add the programming bit.

Comment: I'm concerned about ambiguities with the field of [constructed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language)

Comment: @NikeDattani I think the `dev` part would solve that

Comment: I take that back - `langdev` seems to imply our website is for language development, not design or implementation. I'll change my vote if somebody will edit this.

Comment: @UndoneStudios "development" arguably covers both the terms "design" and "implementation"

Comment: @Seggan I somewhat agree with you on that, but the fact remains that "development" is part of *creating* a language, like "where do I start in making this language", so if we have "development" in our domain name, it will be confusing to newcomers on first sight whether we're a design (and implementation) site or a language-creation site.

Comment: The title will still be "Programming Language Design and Implementation", and this title will be in big text and one of the first things a new user sees. `langdev` is just for the subdomain; I doubt this will mislead many people.

Comment: There is no `dev` in the full name though. Had the site been called "Programming Language Development" or some such instead, it would've made sense.

Comment: @Mast in fact I think it *had* been called that before a name change during definition

Comment: @kaya3 I still wouldn't recommend keeping a somewhat inaccurate subdomain; (at least) to me, language development problems either belong to design, implementation and the "how do I do it" part. Since our site doesn't exclude the final part, people may misunderstand and ask the latter kind of questions (when we reach public beta)

Comment: @UndoneStudios I don't follow your point. You say that "language development" includes design, implementation and "how do I do it", all three of which are on topic here ─ so what is inaccurate?

Comment: Fine, forget that part... but if "language development" is what you say we're about, why did we name ourselves "Programming Language Design and Implementation"? "Language Development" would be a way shorter title, so if we implement this domain, I recommend we also change the title, mainly because the footer looks very weird to me and because of the consistency issue I mentioned before

Comment: How about `proglangdev` for clarity?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe `PLDI` -- short for "programming language design & implementation", same as the conference.

Comment: It's used for well-known abbreviations: [ux.se] - not sure if PLDI already reached that status ...

Comment: The issue is that whenever I see anything "PLDI" I always assume it's about the conference :(

Comment: @tarzh But that means you know exactly what it stands for.

Comment: This is the one people seem to use when they refer to this site already

Answer (score 7):

`pl-design`

`pl` is a well-known acronym for "programming language", and the dash improves readability.

Comment: `pl-dev` as mentioned in another comment would also work by the same logic. Using `dev` as shorthand for "design and implementation" also seems to have some support.

Comment: But I thought "dev" stands for "development", no? Though "Programming Language Development" is an appropriate alternate title

Comment: I consider `development` to be a collection of "design and implementation" tasks, so it's not contradictory from my perspective. But obviously that's just 1 person's opinion...

Answer (score 7):

`pldev`, for Programming Language Development

This has been mentioned in comments but not yet as an answer, and I think it has merit.

**PL** is widespread as an abbreviation of “Programming Language(s)”. It’s more specifically associated with programming languages than “lang”, which can also refer to conlangs. I estimate that there’s not much chance of confusion with other uses of the letters “PL”, like the ISO-639 language code for Polish.

I don’t know of a term of art that clearly covers both design and implementation. **PLT** would work for “Programming Language *Technology*” (and I do describe myself as a “PL technologist”). However, that initialism is in widespread use already for “Programming Language *Theory*”, which doesn’t sound inclusive of engineering & implementation.

“Development” might be slightly more biased toward implementation, but not excessively, and it doesn’t exclude other concerns like usability. There are some alternatives, like “craft” or “art”, but “dev” is a well known abbreviation or suffix for fields of programming; cf. *webdev* and *gamedev*.

Answer (score -1):

`programminglanguages`

Definitely not a fan of this for the site *title*, but for the subdomain, it gets the point across well enough. Even though "programming languages" doesn't necessarily communicate that we *design* them, that is what, e.g., the subreddit equivalent of PLDI is called.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps pldevelopment would be good

Answer (score -1):

Also would like to suggest proglangdev

Answer (score -3):

A simple [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Programming+Language+Design+and+Implementation+pld) turns up suggestions.

Read up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_design_and_implementation), and it seems that the most formal name is [Programming Language Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory), so in the same vein as [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (cstheory) we could have **ldtheory**.

That also provides us our favicon, lambda (derived from the two syllables).

[image: lambda]

But, I guess that makes lambda.stackexchange.com equally valid.

Comment: That is a favicon, not a domain name.

Comment: @star, both have been suggested.

Comment: This site is not focused on theory. It's about design and implementation; theory can play a role in that, but if we were just about theory then the site probably wouldn't exist ([CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [CS Theory SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) both cover PL theory). I think the lambda is the obvious choice for the logo/favicon though.

Answer (score -5):

I would also suggest programminglangdev since to newcomers it might seem like we're creating languages people speak.

Answer (score -6):

`programminglanguagedesign`? It's probably worthwhile to have the 'programming' bit in there somewhere (but it is a bit long)

Answer (score -10):

Finally, I would suggest pldesignandimplementation

Answer (score -22):

I would suggest [programminglanguagedesignandimplementation.stackexchange.com](https://programminglanguagedesignandimplementation.stackexchange.com) it is long but that is the site name after all